# R google analytics Filter

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

This code works great.

```
query.list <- Init(start.date = "2017-12-10",
                   end.date = "2017-12-11",
                   dimension 
 =c("ga:sourceMedium","ga:campaign","ga:landingPagePath"),
                       metrics = c("ga:sessions"),
                       max.results = 20000,
                       #sort = "ga:date",
                       filters="ga:sourceMedium!=drip / sms",
                       table.id = "ga:**********")

    ga.query <- QueryBuilder(query.list)

    ga.data <- GetReportData(ga.query, token,paginate_query = T)
```

However when I change just one line 
filters ga:sourceMedium %3D%3Ddrip / sms there are errors.

```
query.list <- Init(start.date = "2017-12-10",
                   end.date = "2017-12-11",
                   dimensions = c("ga:sourceMedium","ga:campaign","ga:landingPagePath"),
                   metrics = c("ga:sessions"),
                   max.results = 20000,
                   #sort = "ga:date",
                   filters="ga:sourceMedium %3D%3Ddrip / sms",
                   table.id = "ga:*******")

ga.query <- QueryBuilder(query.list)

ga.data <- GetReportData(ga.query, token,paginate_query = T)
```

I just need help with filters. I want exactly equal to operator. Searched here
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference

Comment: try using this to test your filters https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/

Comment: I checked and it worked. But the result in R is not working that is the issue. Additionally Sessions are getting calculated higher

Comment: Also can you help with sessions. The sessions seems to be added rather than single. It is 1 and showing 3.

Comment: have you tried == instead of %3D%3D

Comment: I have tried that out too

Comment: The issue may be with your spaces try doing with filters="ga:sourceMedium %3D%Ddrip%20/%20sms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue may be with your spaces try doing with `filters="ga:sourceMedium %3D%Ddrip%20/%20sms`

as per DaImTo

Comment: **Stack etiquette:**  In the future you should ask the person who gave you the answer in a comment to write a answer that you can accept so that they get points for helping you.  As opposed to just copying it word for word and posting and accepting it yourself.

Comment: Mentioned your name dont want to take credit for what I have not done. Can you do that now..